# Android: How to finish an activity by an ImageView which belongs to the activity in an another class

Tags: android, onclicklistener, activity-finish

I want to finish an activity by an image, and here is what I did:

there's an ImageView in the layout [activity_login.xml] .

```
/**
 * the activity that I want to destroy
 */
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public static LoginActivity activityInstance;

    private ImageView imgBtnBack;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        // for closing this activity by an another class
        activityInstance = this;
        // add event listener
        imgBtnBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_btn_back);
        imgBtnBack.setOnClickListener(new LoginActivityListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}


/**
 * the event handler of LoginActivity
 */
public class LoginActivityListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        context = view.getContext();
        int id = view.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.img_btn_back:  // close the activity by an image
                LoginActivity.activityInstance.finish();
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And I don't know if it was good by the way I did.
can anyone find and tell me a better way to make this work.

Comment: Why do you want to finish the activity? There could be better ways to handle this I we know the reason to finsh the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your onCreate method

```
imgBtnBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_btn_back);
imgBtnBack .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: But   LoginActivityListener implements View.OnClickListener   is an another class that not included in the Activity what I want to close;

Comment: Tell detail about your actual problem.